# Happy Birthday, OR.SE!

Tags: discussion

Operations Research Stack Exchange is now 1 year old! Happy birthday!

OR.SE currently has nearly **1000 questions** and over **2300 users.** We consistently have great questions and great answers. Our community is dedicated and active. Our traffic is good, but it would be great to see it pick up a bit. Let's see what we can do to remind our friends and colleagues about the site.

Here's to the next year!

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to you Larry and to everyone that supported launching this website in 2019. Regarding how we could improve site traffic, I've been thinking some ideas in the last days. A social media campaign to attract users and get more traction (e.g. Twitter, LinkedIn + using adequate hashtags) could be useful, as I've seen many LinkedIn users sharing OR stuff who might benefit from taking part of this site (and this site from having them as active users). There's some recent trend where sites like [Data Science Central](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/video/video/listFeatured) who have been organizing several webinars related to Optimization applications (jointly with Gurobi), so this could be a good moment to expand the outreach in the broader Analytics community.

- For example, we could share the most interesting and upvoted questions/answers, or the ones we like most.
- Share a link to OR.SE and our thoughts/experience from participating in this site. This community might be the only place where one can find researchers, experienced modelers and consultants and users/developers of different OR software - all three together and the convex combinations of them -, and interact in the exchange of ideas and knowledge. There's definitely an added value to be here and lots of potential. As a personal example, in the last months (since joining OR.SE), I've taken at least 2 useful tips with direct application to projects I'm working in.

Also, I recently found out about [r/sysor](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysor/), where we can see more stuff related to OR, for example, scheduling and routing. Maybe some initiative could provide sinergies for both communities (OR.SE and r/sysor).

Answer (score 5):

I am so happy to be a part of this. In my one year of OR.SE membership, I have visited the website for 351 days(05/30/2019 to 05/30/2020) and this journey started by receiving an email from **INFORMS** about OR stack exchange. I believe that by using those kinds of means (sending an email to a large group of people who are in our filed) we can reach our colleagues better. I see recently (a consequence of COVID-19) the number of virtual seminars and workshops increasing and maybe many of us attend those academic gatherings. Those webinars and talks could be a good place to briefly talk about OR.SE and introduce it to our colleagues while virtually sipping our coffee in the break rooms.